# combine lines in dataframe with same identifiant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe as a list:

```
l = [["a",1,2,"","",""],["a",1,2,3,"",""], ["a","",2,"3","4",""],["a",1,"","",4,5]]
```

[image]

I would like to combine all those lines to obtain this final line :

[image]

Ideally, I would flatten the list of lists to fill the blank value where needed. What would be the pythonest way to do that ?

Comment: `df.replace('', np.nan).ffill().tail(1)`

Comment: You do have a bit of a mix of integers typed as int and others typed as string.  Better to get consistent.

Comment: Thx ! Yeah, the thing is my real db as a mix of different value. But everything seems to work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = [["a",1,2,"","",""],["a",1,2,3,"",""], ["a","",2,"3","4",""],["a",1,"","",4,5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)



df.replace('',np.nan).ffill().tail(1)
df_out = df.replace('', np.nan).ffill().tail(1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   0    1    2  3  4    5
3  a  1.0  2.0  3  4  5.0
```